# Minor electric shocks from touching appliances, loose ground?

Tags: ground, ground-loop, shock

I get minor electric shocks when handling everyday home appliances barefoot. These appliances include laptop when the charger is connected and fridge etc. Can the reason for this be loose ground connection?

Additional Information: All appliances have two wires, live and neutral, there is no earth.
We have an inverter for backup power.

Edit: In the country I live in, there are no earth wiring in residential houses.

The shock is not due to static charge, it's continuous steady bearable shock as long as you are in contact.

Comment: Like a static electricity zap, or a continuous effect?

Comment: You probably also need to add detail on what country you live in and how that inverter is connected. I thought most countries would require a ground / earth connection for something like a fridge.

Comment: @Justin: with buzzing sounds and smelly feet?

Comment: If the appliances are designed to be grounded and you do not have them grounded you have a safety issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything with exposed metal parts that are not earth grounded is likely to give you a slight sensation due to capacitive coupling between the external metal parts and internal live parts. The sensation could be strengthened a little if the electrical device is powered by an inverter due to higher leakage to ground of harmonic components of the inverter waveform. In addition, some equipment that is designed to be earth grounded through a 3-prong plug may have intentional capacitive connections to ground and even high resistance connections to ground for the purpose of transient voltage suppression.